# Cannot see the data in mongo db

Tags: angular, mongodb

This is how I insert data to a mongo db:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var user = new User({
        firsName: 'Juan',
        lastName: 'Dela Cruz',
        password: 'super-secret',
        email: email
    });
    user.save();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

This is how I connect:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var appRoutes = require('./routes/app');

var app = express();
// mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/node-angular');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-angular');
```

This is how I create my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    messages: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}]
});

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

I start the mongodb with this command in the command prompt with administrative privileges:

> 'C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program
>   Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe"'

then I try to access it using this command:

> use node-angular
>
> switched to db node-angular
>
> db.users.find()

but I don't get the data in the database. I don't even know if I have successfully updated my database. can you please show me how to this right? Thank you.

Comment: How post method would know the URL of mongoDb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine. You just need to change the collection name's first letter to upper-case.

Instead of,

```
db.users.find();
```

Use

```
db.Users.find();
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

save function has a callback. Try using that and check if there is some error that can be traced. You can do something like this.

```
user.save(function (err) { 
    if (err) return handleError(err); 
    // saved!
  });
```